# Who are the ninjas Team 7 is fighting with in Naruto Shippuden Ending 32?

Tags: naruto

In the [Naruto Shippuden Ending 32](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oooIKzmitXU&t=48s), Naruto, Sasuke, Kakashi and Sakura are fighting against some masked bad guys.

[image]

Who are those people?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, I have a theory about the identity of these bad guys.

Because this was an ending of a canon episode, I would say they didn't exist in the Naruto universe. But if we take a closer look they are wearing Konoha's clothes and [ANBU's](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Anbu) mask. So these bad guys, I think they are [ANBU's](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Anbu)  ninjas (even though some times they don't wear these outfits) who are "chasing" Sasuke.

Also I noticed that these masks are similar to the [mask](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Shinigami_Mask) that Orochimaru found in the [Uzumaki Clan's Mask Storage Temple](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Uzumaki_Clan%27s_Mask_Storage_Temple).

Anyone with more information, please don't hesitate to change this post. :)